# Grabbing data necessary for Oauth2 google using chrome extenion identity.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, identity, google-developers-console

My question is how to grab the  the correct information from the developers console and than apply that to my chrome extension. So far i understand that permission "Identity" need to be included within the manifest. Also that oauth2 with client_id and scopes also need to be added.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/app_identity#update_manifest
The website itself explain to grab the client id within the old versions of the website.

Information that i need to acquire from developers website:
API_Key
Scopes
Key

If possible i would liked further advice concerning the js to be able to grab  the usernames first and last name and other ability such as google drive document creation or edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a wizard on google api site
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js
That gives me all the information i need <3